# Using @PostContruct in Spring @Component to initialize data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using the annotation @PostContruct to initialize some data in @Component using spring.

The problem is the property is initialized only one time. The code inside @Component is something like this.

```
private int x;

@Inject Repository myRepo;

@PostConstruct
private void init () {
    this.x = myRepo.findAll().size();
}
```

Variable "x" will be initilized on build, and if my data change in my DB, "x will not be updated. Is there a way that I could inject service in a class that do not belong to spring? Without @Component, for example.

```
MyClass newclass = new MyClass();
```

So, findAll() will always be called when I initialize the class.

Comment: If the requirement is to change the state of object based on database state, then `@PostContruct` is not the solution. Check Prototype scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do

```
@Component
@Scope('prototype') // thats the trick here
public class MyClass(){

@Autowired Repository myRepo;

@PostConstruct
private void init () {
    this.x = myRepo.findAll().size();
}
}
```

Instances of bean scoped as `prototype` are created everytime they are requested by eithed CDI context or when directly requested from factory.

Alternatively you can do

```
@Component()
public class MyClass(){

    public MyClass(@Autowired Repository myRepo){
      this.x = myRepo.findAll().size();
    }
}
```

In both cases you will have to use Spring's CDI to get new instance of MyClass.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'use Spring's CDI to get new instance of MyClass' ?

Comment: It means that either by `@Autowired`ing it, or using `BeanFactory.getBean(MyClass.class);`